# Use apply or call with "old" context

Tags: javascript

```
B = function(fn) {

    var ex_array = ['a', 'b'];

    this.b_fn = function () {
        fn.apply(what_should_be_there, ex_array);
    }

}

A = function() {

    this.a_fn = function (a, b) {
         //do sth
    }

    var b = new B(fn); 

}
```

Only what I would like to do is use `apply` with on function `fn` in object `b`, but with "old" context, I mean in this case with context of object of class `A`

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your changes.

Comment: It looks to me like B is inheriting from A. Why not just extend A's prototype into B?

Answer (score 0):

## Edit

If you want to use `ex_array` as an array of arguments so that `apply` will iterate through them, do this ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mt0tc57p/3/)):

```
B = function(fn) {

    var ex_array = ['a', 'b'];

    this.b_fn = function() {
      return fn.apply(null, ex_array);  
    };

}

A = function() {

    this.a_fn = function (a, b) {
         console.log(this, a, b);
    }

    var b = new B(this.a_fn.bind(this)); 

    b.b_fn(); // => A {}, "a", "b"

}

new A();
```

## Previous answer

See this [working demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mt0tc57p/):

```
B = function(fn) {

    var ex_array = ['a', 'b'];

    this.b_fn = fn.bind(null, ex_array);

}

A = function() {

    this.a_fn = function (a, b) {
         console.log(this, a);
    }

    var b = new B(this.a_fn.bind(this)); 

    b.b_fn(); // => A {}, ['a', 'b'];

}

new A();
```

Basically, all you need to do is bind `this.a_fn` with its current context. The trick is to use `.bind(null, /* args */)` when making it `this.b_fn`, so it keeps the original `A` context, but allows you to pass in another parameter (in this case, `['a', 'b']`.

Comment: It could be good answer, but I need to upgrade my example, because arguments are not set in class `A`

Comment: @JoshBeam I was surprised to find that calling `fn.bind(null, ...)`, when `fn` is already bound, calls the function in the previously bound context. I couldn't find any references about this.

Comment: @robertklep, yeah, I blame JavaScript for that peculiarity ;) My guess it that when `Function.prototype.bind` sees `null` as the context, it defaults back to the previous context instead of trying to set a new context.

Comment: @JoshBeam yeah that was my guess too :-) BTW, `ex_array` is meant as an array of arguments, not a single argument. So `.apply()` is going to have to be called somewhere.

Comment: @robertklep, yeah makes sense. I updated my answer. In that case, you can just return a function where you call `apply`. Works just the same.

Comment: @JoshBeam, small problem is here. When you print `a` argument I see whole array, not only `'a'`.

Comment: @kspacja, yeah I know, I just updated my answer right when you commented. See the new jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mt0tc57p/2/

Comment: @JoshBeam I think your answer is good and it works on Chrome, but I worry about that will cause problem. Look at this:

Comment: [MDN]https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply - I worry that it will cause problems. According to reference: there could be bound some global object (like `window`)

Comment: @kspacja, what problem would it cause? I would suggest just testing it in the browsers you need it to work in, if you're worried about it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80817/discussion-between-kspacja-and-josh-beam).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution where `a_fn` isn't prebound to an arguments array. I added some logging as demo:

```
var B = function(fn) {
  var ex_array = [ 'a', 'b' ];
  this.b_fn = function () {
    fn(ex_array);
  };
};

var A = function() {
  this.c    = 'hello world';
  this.a_fn = function(a, b) {
    console.log('a:', a);
    console.log('b:', b);
    console.log('c:', this.c);
  };
  var b = new B(Function.prototype.apply.bind(this.a_fn, this));
  b.b_fn();
};
```